# fetch multiple rows of same id in different variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have two rows contaning data of same id.
It has different adresses in different rows for the same id.

I want to fetch both the adress in different variable in php.

How can i do this? Please help!

Below is the code:

```
foreach($row_address as $address)
    {
        echo "<br> Address :" .$address;
        $info=Array(); 
        $data=explode(' ', $address ); 
       $info[1]=$data[0];
       $info[2]=$data[1];
       $info[3]=$data[2];
       echo "City :".$info[1];
       echo "Country :".$info[2];
       echo "Pin Code :".$info[3];

    }

function hoteladdresstable($id)
{
    global $conn;
    /*$sql2 = "select AddressLine from hoteladdress where Hotel_Id= " .$id;
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2,MYSQL_NUM);
    return $row2;*/

    $query = "select AddressLine from hoteladdress where Hotel_Id = " .$id;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $d[] = $row['AddressLine'];
    }
    return $d;
}
```

It gives me both the address of the same id in one variable only.
I want them in two different variables.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You're returning an array, `$d`, that you will have to parse into variables for each address.

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting an array of addresses in `$d`.

What you can do is:

```
$d = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $d[$row['Address_ID']] = $row['AddressLine'];
}
extract($d, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'ad');
```

If you have address ids 2 and 4, you will get two variables

`$ad_2` and `$ad_4`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `mysqli` instead.

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
```

and then

```
foreach($data as $oneRow){
    echo $oneRow['AddressLine']; //and all other stuff that you want.
}
```

you can verify it:

```
print_r($data);
```

Comment: You're echoing instead of assigning each address to a different variable as the OP asked.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: OP can access each and every variable easily as it's assigned to unique key in each `array`

Comment: No doubt, but your answer does not *demonstrate* that.

Comment: @ankitasimlai: you can only return `array` from `function` if you've multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameterized queries. Use PHP's PDO:

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

$STH = $DBH->prepare('select AddressLine from hoteladdress where Hotel_Id = :id');
$STH->bindParam(':name', $id);
$STH->execute();

$d = array();
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
   $d[] = $row['AddressLine'];
}
```

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Don't want your queries getting injected with attacks.